# How to sync staging to production but keep plugin settings

Tags: staging, sync, production

Is there a way to sync my staging and production environments, but keep the settings for certain plugins?

For example, I am using a plugin for the Google tag manager. Each environment has a different container id, set in the plugin settings, that I don't want to be synced.

I understand that the plugin data might be saved in the wp_options table. I can't just skip syncing the table as there are parts of that table that do need to be synced between staging and production.